# How to set the title of a UITabBar System Item?

Tags: ios

I found a system icon that I want to use for a tab bar icon. However, I need to set the title to something other than the default associated with the UITabBarSystemItem.

```
[[UITabBarItem] alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemContacts tag:3]
```

How can I set the title so that it does not use the default of "Contacts"?

Comment: You can use `- (instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title
                        image:(UIImage *)image
                          tag:(NSInteger)tag` method

Comment: yeah but how do I set it to the UITabBarSystemItemContacts icon?

Comment: as per [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarItem/initWithTabBarSystemItem:tag:) `The title and image properties of the returned item cannot be changed later`, so you might need to import an contact icon asset and create new TabbarItem.